# mongoDB object not available in other modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, monk

I am trying to create a a node.js based website where I will have information saved in mongodb

My APP.JS file is given below

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , mongo = require('mongodb')
  , monk = require('monk');

var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){

  req.db = db;
  next();

});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/helloworld', routes.helloworld);
app.get('/userlist', routes.userlist);

//app.use('/users', users);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

And my INDEX.JS file in routes directory is given below

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
};

exports.helloworld = function(req, res){
    res.render('helloworld', { title: 'Express: Hello World' })
};


exports.userlist = function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist',{
            "userlist":docs
        });
    });


    //res.render('userlist', { title: 'Express: User List' })
};
```

I already created user collection using from command prompt

```
db.usercollection.insert({ "username" : "testuser1", "email" : "testuser1@testdomain.com" })
```

Queried it using

```
db.usercollection.find().pretty()
```

And has received the result as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5202b481d2184d390cbf6eca"),
    "username" : "testuser1",
    "email" : "testuser1@testdomain.com"
}
```

But when I try to see output of this browser using

http://localhost:3000/userlist

then I get following error

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at exports.userlist (/var/www/html/node/nodetest1/routes/index.js:17:21)
```

When I do

```
var db = req.db;
console.log(db);
```

Then on console it shows undefined and on browser also it shows db 'undefined' means **db object in APP.JS is not available in ROUTES/INDEX.JS**

I am new to all this stuff so need your help.

Best Regards

Comment: Why not putting your DB stuff in a separate module that you can `require`? I did this some time ago, hope it helps https://gist.github.com/onel0p3z/6299364

Answer (score 0):

Some how I have managed to remove the error.***Following is my updated ROUTES/INDEX.JS file***

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),  
  Server = mongo.Server,
  Db = mongo.Db;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {  
  auto_reconnect: true
});

var db = new Db('nodetest1', server);  

exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
};

exports.helloworld = function(req, res){
    res.render('helloworld', { title: 'Express: Hello World' })
};


exports.userlist = function(req, res){

    var uc = db.collection('usercollection');

    uc.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist',{
            "userlist":docs
        });
    });

    //res.render('userlist', { title: 'Express: User List' })

};
```

I also commented the following lines in APP.JS

```
  //, mongo = require('mongodb')
  //, monk = require('monk');

  //var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Express 4:

> All routing methods will be added in the order in which they appear.
>   You should not do app.use(app.router). This eliminates the most common
>   issue with Express.

*Source https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x*

So this might be the source of your problem.